# problem using UIImage and caf to create video file

Tags: iphone, video, audio, uiimage

I have read all posts I can find on internet about this function, and I have some success to create the video file, but I have 3 problems remaining and seems like no one have mentioned that.

I have 3 problems:

1. the video can't play correctly on some players: quicktime(window), the video play for only one frame and the screen becomes white, and the video can not be played on youtube.
2. some images, for some reason, the image is very abnormal

   http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Jyz-L1k3MEk/TjpfSfKf8LI/AAAAAAAADBs/D1GYuEqI-Oo/h301/1.JPG (ok, they say I'm a new user and don't allow me to post image in the post.)
3. some images, for some reason, orientation is not right, even if I transformed the context according to the orientation, it still not working.

Can some one help me on this please, thank you very much in advance!!

Here is my code:

1: use this function to create video with UIImage, I only used one image, and 1 audio file (caf), and I want to show that image while playing that audio.

```
- (void)writeImageAndAudioAsMovie:(UIImage*)image andAudio:(NSString *)audioFilePath duration:(int)duration {
    NSLog(@"start make movie: length:%d",duration);
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ImageVideoPath] fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                          error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:ImageVideoPath]) 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:ImageVideoPath error:nil];

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.width],AVVideoWidthKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:image.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                    assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                    outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter setShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse:YES];
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    //Write samples:
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage];
    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(duration, 1)];
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];

    CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);
    [videoWriter release];
    [writerInput release];
    [self addAudioToFileAtPath:ImageVideoPath andAudioPath:audioFilePath];
}
```

2. Create CVPixelBufferRef for video

```
-(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image{
    float width = CGImageGetWidth(cgimage);
    float height = CGImageGetHeight(cgimage);

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width,height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,(CFDictionaryRef)options,&pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,width,height,8,4*width,rgbColorSpace,kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,width, height), cgimage);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

3. put video and audio together

```
-(void) addAudioToFileAtPath:(NSString *)vidoPath andAudioPath:(NSString *)audioPath{
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSURL* audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    NSURL* video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:vidoPath];

    NSString *outputFilePath = FinalVideoPath;
    NSURL* outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);
    [audioAsset release];audioAsset = nil;
    [videoAsset release];videoAsset = nil;

    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   
    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         switch (_assetExport.status) 
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 //export complete 
                 NSLog(@"Export Complete");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
             //export error (see exportSession.error)  
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 //export cancelled  
                 break;
         }
      }];    
}
```

Comment: I can help you with the orientation problem , see the answer to my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414351/avmutable-composition-lost-orientation-when-adding-audio-to-a-video-made-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this issue. Here is what is your checkmark list if you want it to get fixed:

1) videos cannot have alpha channel so your pixelBufferFromCGImage should look like this

```
static OSType pixelFormatType = kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB;


- (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image {
    CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image));
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @YES, kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             @YES, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          frameSize.width,
                                          frameSize.height,
                                          pixelFormatType,
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst & kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask;

    //NSUInteger bytesPerRow = 4 * frameSize.width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,
                                                 frameSize.width,
                                                 frameSize.height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent,
                                                 bytesPerRow,
                                                 rgbColorSpace,
                                                 bitmapInfo);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

2) Make sure you are testing on a real device. Simulator tends to distort videos, i had exactly the same problem when producing video using simulator.

3) Make sure you create AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:pixelFormatType] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:imageSize.width] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:imageSize.height] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                          assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                          sourcePixelBufferAttributes:attributes];
```

I still have few other issues but not the distorted video or orientation issue. You would need to rotate image to a proper orientation if you aren't requesting a thumbnail image from asset directly.

Comment: You're god. I had the problem only when the image was in Portrait mode & Landscape was working fine. I dig up the problem I find out the actual problem was in alpha settings. Thanks.