# Trim Audio to Video Length

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a video that is 5 secs long. I have an audio file that is 35 secs long. When I use this code to add audio to Video it makes a resulting video that is 35 secs long.

How can I modify this code so that the audio plays the lenght of the video and stops resulting in a video that is only 5 secs long?

I took this code from this post

[problem using UIImage and caf to create video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938745/problem-using-uiimage-and-caf-to-create-video-file)

```
-(void) addAudioToFileAtPath:(NSString *)vidoPath andAudioPath:(NSString *)audioPath{
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    NSURL* audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    NSURL* video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:vidoPath];

    NSString *outputFilePath = FinalVideoPath;
    NSURL* outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

    AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
    CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);
    [audioAsset release];audioAsset = nil;
    [videoAsset release];videoAsset = nil;

    AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];   
    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {
         switch (_assetExport.status) 
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 //export complete 
                 NSLog(@"Export Complete");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
             //export error (see exportSession.error)  
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Export Failed");
                 NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [_assetExport.error localizedDescription]);
                 //export cancelled  
                 break;
         }
      }];    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_assetExport.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);
```

Comment: I realized it as soon as I posted the question. But you beat me to it. I will mark it correct as soon as I am allowed to